# Issue with updating background color of cell in Excel twice in sub, changing color and back

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which does some calculations and paints a chart. As it takes a while to do so (couple of secs) I thought I make it visible to the user that the process is currently running by changing the the background color of a visible cell at the beginning of the sub and changing it back at the end of the sub after the painting of the chart is done

So basically the sub does

```
sub xyz
   ....
   Range("B1").Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)

   ... than doing some heavy looping

   Range("B1").Interior.Color = RGB(255,255,255)

   ... Error Handling ... 

End Sub
```

hmm, pretty straightforward, I thought . doesnt work as expected.

If I set a breakpoint and step manually through the sub it works as expected, though. 
So I figured it might have to do with the refreshing being done only once the sub ends, and therefore a  created dedicated sub like :

```
 Sub updateColor(cellAddress As String, red As Byte, green As Byte, blue As Byte)
   On Error GoTo ErrHandler
   Range(cellAddress).Interior.Color = RGB(red, green, blue)
   Exit Sub
 ErrHandler:
    Err.Clear
 End Sub

 sub xyz
   ....
   Call updateColor("B1", 255, 0, 0)

   ... than doing some heavy looping

   Call updateColor("B1", 255, 255, 255)

   ... Error Handling ... 

End Sub
```

unfortunately same result. breakpoint and stepping works, but not in one go.

Anybody can point me to the thing I am missing?

Comment: What does "doesnt work as expected" mean? What are you expecting that is not happening?

Comment: I expect to see the background color change to red when I click the button that is calling the sub, and then when the sub is done (which takes about 10s) I expect the background color to turn to white

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps need to see the code you aren't showing.

Comment: Try a `DoEvents` after the color change. Make sure you haven't turned off `Application.ScreenUpdating`. • Only other thing I can imagine: It is running too fast or you are looking to slowly :)

Comment: awesome, that helped. Thank you. 

I had not used application.screenupdating = false anywhere in the code but putting application.screenupdating = true there  explicitly did the trick. thank you

Comment: @CVH Well that means you have `application.screenupdating = false` some where else before in your code. Maybe another sub or function and forgot to turn it on again. Check your code!